# In VS Code, show readable section headings/titles in minimap

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-code, ascii-art

I'm updating some legacy code, because of my unfamiliarity to it, Its very difficult to find structures, especially if I step away for a week for other projects.

To alleviate this problem I've gone back to my old-school roots and started adding ascii text-art as comments above sections of code, using this tool:

http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&h=3&v=1&f=Big%20Money-ne&t=Reveal%0ACheck

This allows me to see via my MiniMap the titles of functions or sections of code I might need to come back to[image: MiniMap with Giant Ascii Titles]

The Thought then occured.. well surely someone else has this problem, and since VSCode seems to be written by the community, maybe someone has already written a plugin that would search the code for function titles (like Javadocs?) and display the title in a readable size?

If not, would it be easily coded? i.e. is the minimap just a very shrunk down copy(not easy) or is it structured and can be parsed and tweaked?

Answer (score 1):

As long as your language plugin supports it, you can use `cmd + shift + o` to go to function definition.
All functions should also be listed in the Side Bar under "Outline"

Comment: Under normal circumstances, where you know the name of the functions and just need to type it, this might work. But in a 20k lines file cowboy-spaghetti-code, I don't know even 1/100th of the functions, purposes, names or anything. The only thing that seems to help is the ability to quickly glance at the minimap, which would be helped if I could deliminate between functions at a glance

Comment: So you don’t have them in the Outline section of Explorer tan in Side Bar?

Comment: Its a mishmash of .NET, PHP and JavaScript with jquery 1.4, so even VS Outline doesn't recognise anything.